# Find matching data in another excel worksheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to set up a spreadsheet to find out which of the products that I am selling are out of stock. I get a data feed in excel from my supplier which is updated every day.

I have the product code in worksheet 1 and the list of products that are out of stock from my supplier in worksheet 2. How do I set up a formula which will check if each product code in worksheet 1 exists in worksheet 2 and return a out of stock value if it is found in worksheet 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that on `worksheet1` the product codes start in `A1`, and the product codes in `worksheet2` also start in `A1`, then you can combine a `VLOOKUP()` and `IFERROR()`.

In `worksheet1`, column `B1`, next to a product code insert:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(worksheet1!A1,worksheet2!$A:$A,1,FALSE)=worksheet1!A1, 
"In Stock"), "Out of Stock")
```

This looks to see if the product code from `worksheet1` can be found in `worksheet2`. If it cannot be found the `VLOOKUP()` will give an error, hence the `IFERROR()` function.

This formula can then be dragged down to check all your product codes.

Comment: Many thanks, this worked perfectly, all I had to do was switch "In Stock" and "Out of Stock" around. You have saved me from half an hour of checking products each day!